# Get SPWeb at all the levels

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spweb, spsite

I have a root site with sites at different levels(depth is unknown). How can I find all the SPWeb objects iterating till the deepest level.

will the below code give me desired result

```
SPWebApplication mySPWebApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("http://test-site"));
{
    foreach (SPSite siteCollection in mySPWebApp.Sites)
    {
        foreach (SPWeb oweb in siteCollection.AllWebs)
        {
            //My Code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, with [SPWebApplication.Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.sites.aspx) you get all site collections in a web application and with [SPSite.AllWebs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.allwebs.aspx) you get all sites in a site collection no matter the level.

> Best practice is to dispose explicitly of individual Web sites that are retrieved from the collection that is returned through the AllWebs property.

```
foreach (SPWeb oweb in siteCollection.AllWebs)
{
     try
     {
           //Your code
     }
     finally
     {
          oweb.Dispose();
     }
}
```

You should dispose site collections too.

Comment: Disposing is good. Best practice is to dispose in a try catch or using statement

Comment: @TomResing The “best practice” [sentence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.allwebs.aspx) in my answer is from Microsoft, that’s why I’ve put that as a quote. I agree that “best practice” is overused and sometimes misused (not just by Microsoft) and very often it should be “good to”, “should”, or “must” instead of “best practice”. I’ll edit my answer to add your suggestion for try/finally. Thanks.

Comment: Good update @naim!

Answer (score 3):

To build on @naim's answer, you should dispose both the Site Collections and the webs and use try/catch around the dispose or using statements.

## Site Collection Dispose Example

from [Best Practices: Using Disposable Windows SharePoint Services Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

```
void SPSiteCollectionForEachNoLeak()
{
    using (SPSite siteCollectionOuter = new SPSite("http://moss"))
    {
        SPWebApplication webApp = siteCollectionOuter.WebApplication;
        SPSiteCollection siteCollections = webApp.Sites;

        foreach (SPSite siteCollectionInner in siteCollections)
        {
            try
            {
                // ...
            }
            finally
            {
                if(siteCollectionInner != null)
                    siteCollectionInner.Dispose();
            }
        }
    } // SPSite object siteCollectionOuter.Dispose() automatically called.
}
```

## Web Dispose Example

from [Best Practices: Using Disposable Windows SharePoint Services Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

```
void SPWebCollectionAddNoLeak(string strWebUrl)
{
    using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://moss"))
    {
        using (SPWeb outerWeb = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPWebCollection webCollection = siteCollection.AllWebs; // No AllWebs leak just getting reference.
            using (SPWeb innerWeb = webCollection.Add(strWebUrl))
            {
                //...
            }
        } // SPWeb object outerWeb.Dispose() automatically called.
    }  // SPSite object siteCollection.Dispose() automatically called. 
}
```